# Wrong aspect ratio picture in Basic Card (Google Action)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, aspect-ratio

I've set up my first Google Action (basic) and when I test it (console.actions.google.com) the pictures in a basic card are shown in their original ratio. When I deploy the agent made in Dialogflow the pictures are distorted with the wrong aspect ratio. Too small. No matter what ratio the original picture has they all are changed to 2:3 (w:h).

[Example Android One, Nokia 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRuWp.png)

[Screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Vi5.jpg)
[Screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcSaD.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is difficult to answer your question without a lot more information. If you can update your question to show sample code that illustrates the problem, and possibly some example pictures, we may better be able to help you. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't use code. I'm a beginner at this. Only use the basics of Dialogflow.

Comment: Can you show screen shots of how you have configured this in Dialogflow, then?

Comment: See 2 screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this issue can't be fixed with dialogflow alone. To fix this issue, you should build the card response via a fulfillment. The property `'display' : 'CROPPED'`. takes care of the image resizing. You can use the inline editor for this. I've added a code sample that can be used in the inline editor.

For more info, check the documentation from Google: https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/rich-responses#BasicCardSamples

```
function cardFunction(agent) {
  let conv = agent.conv();
  
  conv.ask(new BasicCard({
    text: `This is a basic card.  Text in a basic card can include "quotes" and
    most other unicode characters including emojis.  Basic cards also support
    some markdown formatting like *emphasis* or _italics_, **strong** or
    __bold__, and ***bold itallic*** or ___strong emphasis___ as well as other
    things like line  \nbreaks`, // Note the two spaces before '\n' required for
                                 // a line break to be rendered in the card.
    subtitle: 'This is a subtitle',
    title: 'Title: this is a title',
    buttons: new Button({
      title: 'This is a button',
      url: 'https://assistant.google.com/',
    }),
    image: new Image({
      url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
      alt: 'Image alternate text',
    }),
    display: 'CROPPED',
  }));

  agent.add(conv)
}
```

Comment: OK thanks, strange that it is a default setting.(?).